# EclispeRCP: Do something after program is loaded

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I want do something after my eclipse rcp has fully started up. What would be the best entry point for that (maybe an extension point)?

For my purpose I want to do some changes on an editor and save it after my application has started up.

Comment: Why do you want to change something, when eclipse is just started? Could you provide more information about what actually you want to do.

Comment: Basically I wanted to write initial values to an xml file I'm using. By now I already found a fitting place for this inside my code. I was expecting soemthin like an afterStartup() methode for the eclispe rcp after all plugins are loaded and the gui is painted.

Comment: There is a set of methods in the WorkbenchWindowAdvisor, one of them is 'postStartup()', which may be something you are looking for.

Comment: There is no way to mark your comment as the correct answer or is there? Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem:) I will add an this comment as an answer, so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a set of methods in the `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor`, one of them is `'postStartup()'`, which may be something you are looking for.